# Reading 8 byte chunks from lsm file format in java

Tags: java, image

I have stacks of lsm files which I need to analyze. My first task is to read 8 byte chunks from the image opened in txt format...

Here's what I've done so far, but this obviously only reads the first four-letter substring of the text and doesn't proceed to read the rest:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Image {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        System.out.println("Input image text in unicode now...");

        Scanner image = new Scanner (System.in);

        String imageInput = image.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageInput.length(); i+=4) {
            int x = -4;
            int y = 0;
            x+=4;
            y+=4;
            String toArray = imageInput.substring(x,y);

            System.out.println(toArray + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

How do I get it to read the next four-letter chunk and put each chunk in an array?

Comment: You need to read the files in binary, not as text (so don't use `Scanner`). You are probably better off using [a library](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/lsm-reader.html).

Comment: okay so i figured out that x and y need to be defined outside the for loop, but how do i get these chars into a string []?

Comment: You can call the String constructor that accepts a byte array. But make sure you also specify the character encoding; if unsure look up the encoding within the specification of the lsm file format. Don't go the C way and confuse characters and binary data though. A char is not a byte.

Comment: You can't; a `String` is not made to store binary data!

Comment: Or try [this tutorial about accessing random access files, straight "from the source"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)